# Why doesn't Feynman take the real part of a complex EM wave before finding the intensity?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, complex-numbers

This is from The Feynman Lectures vol 2 chapter ch 33 on reflection of complex EM waves on metal. 
[image]

In the above I would expect $\frac{I_r}{I_i} = \frac{Re(E'_0)^2}{Re(E_0)^2}$,  rather then $\frac{I_r}{I_i} = \frac{E^{'2}_0}{E^{2}_0}$, as we should be able to discard the imaginary part of the EM - wave before making the calculation of intensity.

Obviously $\frac{E^{'2}_0}{E_0^2} \ne \frac{Re(E'_0)^2}{Re(E_0)^2}$, what am I missing here?

Comment: Feynman is calculating the ratio of the incident and reflected *average powers*, i.e, ratio of the square moduli of the complex amplitudes, and so does everybody else when interested in reflectivity and transmissivity (EEs call that the reflection and transmssion "gains"). You have a typo in your last equation, you need squares.

Comment: @hyportnex, thank you for answering my question. :)

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.